# Как определить количество различных элементов матрицы в C++

Tags: c++, матрицы

Всем доброго времени суток! Хотел бы попросить вас о помощи. Не могу понять, как сделать следующее задание. Нужно сделать следующее задание:  "Задана символьная матрица размером NxM. Определить количество различных элементов матрицы (т.е. повторяющиеся элементы считать один раз)."

Тело следующее:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

int main(){
    using std::setlocale; // следующие 2 строчки - РУССК ЯЗ
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

    int i,n,m,k,j;

    printf ("Введите кол-во строк массива не более 15 элементов, n = ");
      scanf("%d",&n);
      printf ("Введите кол-во столбцов массива не более 15 элементов, m = ");
      scanf("%d",&m);

    int **mas;
    mas=new int *[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) mas[i]=new int[m];

   srand(time(0));

    printf("Выберите тип ввода: 1-c клавиатуры, 2-с помощью rand() ");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    if ((k>0)&&(k<=2))
    {

      printf("Массив mas \n");
      switch(k) {
        case 2: for (i=0; i<n; i++){
                    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
                      mas[i][j] = rand()%21-10;     // Заполнение массива А случайными числами вдиапазоне -10..10
                      printf("%4d",mas[i][j]);}
                      printf("\n");
                    }

                break;
         case 1: for (i=0; i<n; i++)
                    for(j=0;j<m;j++)scanf("%d",&mas[i][j]);
                 break;
      }
    }


    bool p= true;
    while (p==true){
        p=false;
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            int sum1=0, sum2=0;
            for(j=0;j<m;j++){
                sum1+=mas[i][j];
                sum2+=mas[i+1][j];
            }
            if(sum1>sum2){
                for(j=0;j<m;j++){
                    int tmp=mas[i][j];
                mas[i][j]=mas[i+1][j];
                mas[i+1][j]=tmp;
                }
                p=true;
            }
            //
        }
    }

        printf("Результат: \n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(j=0;j<m;j++){
                printf("%4d",mas[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "символьная матрица" - ??

Comment: да, символьная.

Comment: что это значит?

Comment: вот и я особо не понял

Comment: "символьная матрица" Скорее всего имелось ввиду матрица из символов, то есть матрица из букв, то есть из переменных типа char в которые записаны буквы, а не управляющие символы. Ну, или матрица из wchar_t, для эстетов.

Answer (score 1):

Символьная матрица значит матрица из символов. Тип char занимает 1 байт значит он может отображать один из 2^8 символов. Вообщем предлагаю так:

```
bool used[256];//256 это 2^8
char mas[n][m];
int k=0;//счетчик
//заполняем масив mas это без меня напишите
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        if(!used[(int)a[i][j]])/*если впервые этот символ*/{k++;used[(int)a[i][j]]=true;}
    }
}
```

в итоге k это количество различных символов